# Prevent click firing after swipe on desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchswipe

I am using touchswipe for a web app, but I would also like it to work on the desktop (specifically chrome). However it is firing the click after a swipe. Is there a way to prevent it doing this ?

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/symeon/sbvvs4ab/) for this

```
    $(".swiper").swipe({
        tap: function(event, target) {
            alert('tap');
        },
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount){
            alert('swipe');
        }
    });
    $(".swiper").on("click",function () {alert("click")});
```

I have tried return false , stopPropogation etc but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Latest Js** https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.js

see this [discussion](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/70)

And git [diff](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/commit/f226567f5bf8fc2bdbee5ae7dac1fc80e71beda8)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/quycddab/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var swipFlag = false;
    $(".swiper").swipe({
        tap: function (event, target) {
            alert('tap');
        },
        swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            console.log(event)

            alert('swipe');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Keval.  what i want to do  is stop the click event of the .swiper element - see http://jsfiddle.net/symeon/quycddab/2/  you can see each time i swipe it also does the click.

Comment: yes i have one solution and i created first fiddle of that see this http://jsfiddle.net/symeon/quycddab/  in this fiddle i used your js

Comment: Ahh ok - so you are just setting a flag - i did wonder if there was something within touchswipe that did this. thanks anyway.

Comment: because i tried with stop propagation prevent default and return false but its not working because your onclick and swip event both register separately . and so i think use new js which is mention in answer you can see diff of js they added  tap for click so your click event and tap event both work